# Java watchservice, how to find the directory where the file was created?

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to use Java Watchservice (NIO) to watch mutiple directories , I can see the create event in all directories but I cant trace back to directory where the file was created.

For eg , whenever a new file is created I can only see a filename (without path) , how to know whether the create event triggered on faxfolder or faxfolder2

```
System.out.println("START MONITORING  **************");


Path faxFolder = Paths.get("E:\\activiti\\monitor\\m1");
Path faxFolder2 = Paths.get("E:\\activiti\\monitor\\m2");
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
faxFolder2.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);


boolean valid = true;
WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
    WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
    if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
        String fileName = event.context().toString();
        System.out.println(fileName);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register the watchService, you are given a `WatchKey` for that directory. You should remember which key goes with which directory.

```
System.out.println("START MONITORING  **************");


Path faxFolder = Paths.get("E:\\activiti\\monitor\\m1");
Path faxFolder2 = Paths.get("E:\\activiti\\monitor\\m2");
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
Map<WatchKey,Path> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
WatchKey watchKey1 = faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
keyMap.put(watchKey1, faxFolder);
WatchKey watchKey2 = faxFolder2.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
keyMap.put(watchKey2, faxFolder2);


while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
    Path dir = keyMap.get(watchKey);
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
        WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
            Path relativePath = (Path) event.context();
            String fileName = dir.resolve(relativePath).toString();
            System.out.println(fileName);

        }
    }
}
```

Your monitoring loop should wait for events (`WatchService.take()`) and then resolve the events (`watchKey.pollEvents()`). All of which will be applicable to the same `WatchKey`. Then take the next key, which may be for another directory.

Comment: You don't technically need this as you can always get the monitored path from the `WatchKey` you get from `WatchService#take()` (use the `WatchKey#watchable()` method).  You need to keep the mapping if you have to handle directory creation/remove as well as file manipulations.

Answer (score -1):

```
Path newFile = ev.context();
Path absolutePath = newFile.toAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: It works only if it watches for the current working directory.